# Mongoose query not running - "cursor.toArray is not a function"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDB beginner, having trouble getting queries to work. Was following a tutorial of sorts and it was a demo notes app. Their syntax for saving new notes works fine.

However when it comes to printing out the list of notes, there seems to be something wrong in the syntax given to me or something im doing wrong.

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const url =
    "mongodb+srv://Saif:<password>@cluster0.8d2lb.mongodb.net/notes-app?retryWrites=true&w=majority";

mongoose.connect(url, {
    useNewUrlParser: true,
});

const noteSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    content: String,
    date: Date,
    important: Boolean,
});

const Note = mongoose.model("Note", noteSchema);

Note.find({}).then((result) => {
    result.forEach((note) => {
        console.log(note);
    });
    mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

After looking up documentation, the actual syntax of `find` is a little different where they pass in a callback instead of using promises. But changing that block to use a callback still doesnt work

```
Note.find({}, (error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        
    } else {
        data.forEach((note) => {
            console.log(note);
        })   
    }
    mongoose.connection.close()

})
```

**Error**

```
TypeError: cursor.toArray is not a function
    at model.Query.<anonymous> (D:\Folders\Documents\CS.........

(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:27108) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:27108) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Answer (score 0):

`.find` method from model returns Query object not Cursor

For cursor you need to do `.exec`

```js
Note.find({}).exec((error, data) => {
    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
        
    } else {
        data.forEach((note) => {
            console.log(note);
        })   
    }
    mongoose.connection.close()

})
```

Comment: still returns the same cursor error. I dont even know what a cursor is. When do i want a query object and when do i want a cursor? And why doesnt your example work

Comment: turns out theres some problems related to this on mongoose version 6.0 so i just installed version v5.13.8 and my example works fine

Comment: Alright, You can try to create issue on Mongoose and let them know about the error :) OSS contributions you know!